# How to delete current user credentials from awsebcli?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, boto

Started working on my other laptop and noticed that it has old EB credentials stored in.

How can I "reset" awsebcli. I want `eb init` command to ask me to specify new aws credentials but cannot figure how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to type this command and enter your new credentials in the interactive session.

```
aws configure
```

Or you can go to this file `~/.aws/config` and edit them

Comment: Ah, thanks! Does this mean it's sharing credentials with awscli?

Comment: Yes it is sharing the creds